# Can't import gradle android project in Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm getting to know gradle and I work with Intellij Idea 13.1.3 with Android plugin.
I want to build [u2020](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) project and face some troubles with using gradle in Idea.

After importing the project all I get is single module 'u2020' with no dependencies set and meaningless project structure. Also Idea doesn't recognize the android framework of project, doesn't see .java files like classes.

There is single build.gradle file in the root. 
What should I do in order to run project in Idea? Add sourceSets to build.gradle?

UPD:
build.gradle from github link:

```
buildscript {    
  repositories {    
    mavenCentral()    
  }    
  dependencies {    
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'    
  }    

}       

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

  compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
  provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.8.0'

  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
  debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.madge:madge:1.1.1'
  debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.scalpel:scalpel:1.1.1'

  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.3'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'

  compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.3'
}

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

def isTravis = "true".equals(System.getenv("TRAVIS"))
def preDexEnabled = "true".equals(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

  dexOptions {
    // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
    preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !isTravis
  }

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21

    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

    buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
      versionNameSuffix '-dev'
    }
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}
```

Folders in the project

```
u2020    
|    
|_debug    
| |_AndroidManifest.xml
| |_java
| |_res
| |_assets
|
|_main
| |_androidManifest.xml
| |_java
| |_all other android stuff
|
|_release
| |_java
|
|_build.gradle
|_other stuff
```

Comment: We need a LOT more infos. Project structure, build.gradle files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely IJ's Gradle project import is not Android aware and imports correctly Java projects that have `java` plugins applied. `com.android.application` extends `java-base` but not `java`. The simplest solution can be to use Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio handled the project well. Thanks for the explanation of this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Just import this project as gradle module in idea. And it's must work.

[image]